# Angular remove query param

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How would I remove a query parameter from the URL? For example from `www.expample.com/home?id=123&pos=sd&sd=iii` to `www.expample.com/home?id=123&sd=iii`

EDIT:
This is my version:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(c => {
  const params = Object.assign({}, c);
  delete params.dapp;
  this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, queryParams: params });
}).unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can remove a query parameter by using the `merge` option of `queryParamsHandling` and passing in `null` for any params you wish to remove.

```
// Remove query params
this.router.navigate([], {
  queryParams: {
    'yourParamName': null,
    'youCanRemoveMultiple': null,
  },
  queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
})
```

This option is simpler and requires less work to ensure you are not removing other params. You also do not need to worry about cleaning up an observable subscription when your component is destroyed.

Comment: Any ideas how to remove a single item from a query parameter that is an array (e.g. given `/path?p=a&p=b&p=c`, how to remove `p=c` only)?

Comment: This way of doing it works especially well when you have dynamic query params that come from other parts of the app and you only want to remove very specific params without interfering with what else might have been added somewhere else.

Comment: It is worth noting that this will trigger navigation event. I had an issue when clearing the params within angular guard - navigation was cancelled

Comment: You can use the option `skipLocationChange` to prevent it from triggering a navigation event.

Comment: Be aware that `router.navigate()` is asynchronous. So if you try to remove two query params by calling `router.navigate()` twice within the same task (event loop frame) - only the second param will actually be deleted from the url.

Answer (score 31):

**UPDATE:** @epelc's answer below is the up-to-date and correct way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193044/5932590.

---

Unfortunately, there is no clear-cut way to do this currently: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18011. However, as jasonaden commented on the linked thread,

> This could be done manually by merging the old and new query params, removing the key you don't want.

Here is one way to do that:

Let's say you have your queryParams stored in some properties.

```
class MyComponent() {
  id: string;
  pos: string;
  sd: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe(next => {
      const paramMap = next.queryParamMap;
      this.id = paramMap.get('id');
      this.pos = paramMap.get('pos');
      this.sd = paramMap.get('sd');
    });
  }
}
```

A method to clear the `pos` parameter would look like this:

```
clearPosParam() {
  this.router.navigate(
    ['.'], 
    { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { id: this.id, sd: this.sd } }
  );
}
```

This will effectively navigate to the current route and clear your `pos` query parameter, keeping your other query parameters the same.

Comment: Glad to help, consider "accepting" the answer by clicking the checkmark so other people know your question has been answered. And welcome to SO!

Comment: This leaks an observable subscription. `Router` does not automatically cleanup the subscription to `route.url.subscribe` and must be manually tracked and disposed when the component is destroyed. Please consider my answer below which doesn't require any subscriptions and is simpler.

Comment: I prefer this to @epelc's answer because I don't have to specify what properties of the query params object I want to clear. I'm working on a generic faceted search component, I don't know the properties in the component that's implementing this, I just need that component to manage adding and removing values and I prefer to only specify properties that actually have a value to keep the url short.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking to do exactly this, but without using the router. Here is what I came up with:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

declare location: Location; // get this from dependency injection

const [path, query] = location.path().split('?');
const params = new HttpParams({ fromString: query });
const theValueIWant = params.get('theParamIWant');
location.replaceState(path, params.delete('theParamIWant').toString());
```

Comment: Very nice! Even works in APP_INITIALIZER

Answer (score 3):

This is the best sulotion that i found, you can change url parameters

in constructor use

```
    private _ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
```

then use this in init or in constructor body

```
    var snapshot = this._ActivatedRoute.snapshot;
    const params = { ...snapshot.queryParams };
    delete params.pos
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: params });
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written a few Router Prototype overrides that makes things easier to handle query params:

The idea is to call a method on the router to easily manage routing via parameters, instead of having to export functions/redeclare the functionality every time.

Create an `index.d.ts` file that contains the prototype override definitions:

```
// Ensure this is treated as a module.
export { };

declare module '@angular/router' {
    interface Router {
        updateQueryParams(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, params: Params): Promise<boolean>;
        setQueryParams(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, params: Params): Promise<boolean>;
        removeQueryParams(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, ...keys: string[]): Promise<boolean>;
    }
}
```

> **Important**:
>
> Make sure you import this file before using this prototype override, I just added my prototype import(s) to the `app.module.ts`:
>
> `import './shared/prototype-overrides/router.prototypes';`

---

### Setting Query Parameters

> This will only set the query parameters specified, and not merge the parameters.

#### Scenario

You are on the following route:

`http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param1=Test&param2=test2`

and you want to **SET** the query parameters to `param3=HelloWorld`, removing the others.

#### Usage

```
this.router.setQueryParams(this.activatedRoute, { param3: 'HelloWorld' });

// Will route to http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param3=HelloWorld
```

#### Prototype function implementation

```
Router.prototype.setQueryParams = function (activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, params: Params): Promise<boolean> {
    const context: Router = this;

    if (isNullOrUndefined(activatedRoute)) {
        throw new Error('Cannot update the query parameters - Activated Route not provided to use relative route');
    }

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(context.navigate([], {
                relativeTo: activatedRoute,
                queryParams: params
            }));
        });
    });
};
```

---

### Updating Query Parameters

> This is used to just easily update the queryParams, which will **merge** the query parameters in the route, so you don't have duplicate query parameters.

#### Scenario

You are on the following route:

`http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param1=Test&param2=test2`

and you want to **UPDATE** only the one query parameter, `param1` to `param1=HelloWorld`, and leave the others as they are.

#### Usage

```
this.router.updateQueryParams(this.activatedRoute, { param1: 'HelloWorld' });

// Will route to http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param1=HelloWorld&param2=test2
```

#### Prototype function implementation

```
Router.prototype.updateQueryParams = function (activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, params: Params): Promise<boolean> {
    const context: Router = this;

    if (isNullOrUndefined(activatedRoute)) {
        throw new Error('Cannot update the query parameters - Activated Route not provided to use relative route');
    }

    // setTimeout required because there is an unintended behaviour when rapidly firing router updates in the same repaint cycle:
    // 
    // NavigationCancel - Navigation ID 2 is not equal to the current navigation id 3
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802182/1335789
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(context.navigate([], {
                relativeTo: activatedRoute,
                queryParams: params,
                queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
            }));
        });
    });
};
```

---

### Removing Query Parameters

#### Scenario

You are on the following route:

`http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param1=Test&param2=test2&param3=test3`

and you want to **REMOVE** only the one (or more, separated keys by string) query parameter, `param1`, and leave the others as they are.

#### Usage

```
this.router.removeQueryParams(this.activatedRoute, 'param1');

// Will route to http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param2=test2&param3=test3

//Removing multiple parameters:
this.router.removeQueryParams(this.activatedRoute, 'param1', 'param3');

// Will route to http://localhost:4200/#/some-route?param2=test2
```

#### Prototype function implementation

```
Router.prototype.removeQueryParams = function (activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, ...keys: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
    const context: Router = this;

    const currentParams: any = {};
    Object.keys(activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams).forEach(key => {
        currentParams[key] = activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams[key];
    });
    keys?.forEach(key => {
        delete currentParams[key];
    });

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() =>
            resolve(context.setQueryParams(activatedRoute, currentParams))
        );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing Query Params:

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
}

setQueryParams(){
    const qParams: Params = {};
    this.router.navigate([], {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams: qParams,
        queryParamsHandling: ''
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native javascript operation to remove queryParams from url and navigate to View using `navigateByUrl` method

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl

```
this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        if (params && Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
          const urlWithoutQueryParams = this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf('?'));
          this.router.navigateByUrl(urlWithoutQueryParams)
            .then(() => {
            // any other functionality when navigation succeeds
              params = null;
            });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works very well:

```
  async removeQueryParams(keys: string[]) {
    if (keys?.length) {
      const queryParams01 = { ...this._ActivatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams };

      keys.forEach((key) => {
        delete queryParams01[key];
      });

      await this._Router.navigate([], {
        relativeTo: this._ActivatedRoute,
        queryParams: queryParams01,
        queryParamsHandling: "",
        replaceUrl: true,
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Step 1: Declare a global url search param.

```
  incomingUrlParams: URLSearchParams;
```

Step 2: Save the query in the urlsearchparam global variable

```
this.incomingUrlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Step 3: Call this anywhere when the params has been saved:

```
clearQueryParamenters() {
      let queryParamsJsonString: string = "";      
      this.incomingUrlParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
        queryParamsJsonString += '"' + key + '":' + null + ',';
      });
      queryParamsJsonString = "{" + queryParamsJsonString.trim().replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "") + "}";
      this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: JSON.parse(queryParamsJsonString),
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
      })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the above solution was fine for me. Until i tried this approach.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css']
})
export class MyComponentComponent {
  constructor(private location: Location) { }

  changeUrl() {
    const newUrl = '/prepare/this/url/yourself/and/exclude/parameter';
    this.location.replaceState(newUrl);
  }
}
```

This replaces the parameter's version of URL with **newUrl** and good thing is that the components don't get re-rendered.
For more info about **replaceState** [here](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replacestate) it is.