# Angular - Remove URL parameters on page refresh

Tags: angular

I am adding a parameter to URL when clicking on a 'EDIT' button

```
    public editCustomFields() {      
      this.router.navigate(['.'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { view: 'edit' }});      
    }
```

Thenk the URL becomes

```
https://someurl.com/grids/admin/custom-fields?view=edit
```

But, when I manually refresh the browser, I am not able to remove those parameters from the URL. Please suggest on how can I this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552993/angular-5-remove-query-param/52193044#52193044

Comment: so, when do I call this?

Comment: When you navigate to your desired component and want to remove the query parameter

Answer (score 1):

In ngOnInit:

```
this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: {} });
```

will stay in the same page, and remove the query params after manual refresh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).