# One tab not navigating

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

Angular project. Used by Router. There is a navigation bar with 8 items. The transition to tab 2 does not occur if you go from tab 4. Any other combination works. How to catch the problem in this situation, how to debug it? In a subscription to route.events, nothing happens when this situation is reproduced, I look through the console, in other cases it works.

Answer (score 0):

The question, of course, turned out to be blurry, sorry everyone)) The problem was solved, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316794/navigation-id-is-not-equal-to-the-current-router-navigation-id-error)