# routerLinkActive don't trigger the good link

Tags: angular, angular-router

So I have read some articles on the subject, without found an answer.

**USE CASES**

- If the app is launch on the `/tools` route, it's working. Then I switch to `/audio`, it's working.
- If the app is launch on the `/audio` route, it's working. Then I switch to `/tools`, it's NOT working. The active item is still 'Audio' and I don't know why.

**PROBLEM**

The `active` class is not added to the good item.

app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'tools', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'tools', component: ToolsComponent },
      {
        path: 'audio',
        loadChildren: () => import('./audio/audio.module').then(m => m.AudioModule)
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

audio.module :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AudioComponent, AudioDetailsComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule, AudioRoutingModule],
})
```

audio.routing.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AudioComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: AudioDetailsComponent }
];
```

menu.component.html (which is in HomeComponent) :

```
<mat-nav-list fxLayout="column">
  <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/tools']" routerLinkActive="active">
    <span mat-line>Tools</span>
    <mat-icon matListIcon>build</mat-icon>
  </a>
  <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/audio']" routerLinkActive="active">
    <span mat-line>Audio</span>
    <mat-icon matListIcon>headset</mat-icon>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: no need of brackets in case of static binding `[routerLink]="['/audio']"`, any error in console?

Comment: I tried with and without. No changes. But thanks ! No error in console neither :/

Comment: try debugging the routing transaction using `enableTracing` for more information refer here https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Comment: When I click on `/tools`, I have a NavigationCancel event with the error `Navigation ID 3 is not equal to the current navigation id 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "Why" it's not working :
In audio.component.ts, I call `router.navigate` in quick succession. [This answer solved my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802182/6444705)

I juste have to reformat my code.